# Access port on machine by connecting to other machine via SSH?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have to access my home router's web interface on port 80. Unfortunately, the only way into the network I have at the moment is SSH to *another* machine on the same network.

```
me ---|---SSH Box----Home Router
```

My Google foo seems to have abandoned me, I couldn't didn't find anything helpful. Any ideas? Thanks!

To clarify: I'm not at home right now. I do however have access to one machine on the network (a QNAP NAS) over SSH. I need to access the home router web interface on port 80 from my notebook which is outside of the home network.

Comment: Clarify more - I don't actually see what you want to do. SSH to the router? Access the router's web interface from a remote computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
ssh -L8080:HOMEROUTER:80 HOME_SSH_SERVER
```

and stay logged in.  Then point your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and it should connect to your router.